# Kotlin Push уведомления?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase

у меня есть приложения по записи на автомойку, как я могу сделать уведомления когда время записи совпадает с текущим временем?

Я слышал про firebase, но так и не понял толком

Comment: Маловато деталей для ответа. Сам Firebase это не про уведомления, а про пуши (т.е. про доставку с гуглового сервера к-л информации приложению, которая может, но не обязана, быть показана через уведомление). Тут, по идее, главное - выяснить есть ли у вас свой сервер. Если да и запись на автомойку через него идёт, то там пуши и отправляйте кроном проходясь по БД. С андроида надо будет на бэк токены пушей передать и пуши принимать и показывать уведомление. Если своего сервера нет - то локально через WorkManager проверяйте текущее время и время записи и показывайте уведомление.

Comment: Своего сервера нет, поэтому про firebase спросил, если через WorkManager делать и если приложение закрыто то как быть?

Comment: Прочитал про WorkManager кажись это то что мне надо

Comment: А можешь рассказать по подробней про логику через WorkManager? Если не затруднит тебя, буду признателен

Comment: Если совсем примерно - надо создать воркер класс, в нём написать нужную логику (сверку времени и вывод уведомления). Сам этот воркер надо запустить через WorkManager с указанием, что он должен периодически выполняться. Надо только иметь в виду, что минимальный период меж запусками - около 15 минут. Т.е. это максимальная точность по времени у вас будет. И не будут никак учтены пользовательские изменения часового пояса например. Ну и система может вмешиваться в работу этого всего (хотя это и для любого другого решения так) в смысле несрабатывания воркера в ожидаемое время.

Comment: Н вот я почитал и меня напрягает эти 15 минут, я так и не сообразил как это можно реализовать, слыхал ещё про onesignal, но конечно хотелось бы это реализовать без посторонних ресурсов

Comment: Любые встреченные вами реализации пушей будут требовать своего сервера и являться не более чем обёрткой над FCM. Все возможные костыли, которые позволят использовать FCM без своего сервера сложны, запутаны и ненадёжны, лучше уж свой сервер поднять. Как один из возможных костылей - слать FCM токены юзеров в Firestore, откуда они будут читаться каким-то  отдельным приложением на вашем личном телефоне, который будет всегда включён в розетку, настроен на неспать 24/7 и в бесконечном цикле обновлять данные с Firestore и слать пуши через FCM. Т.е. что-то типа своего сервера, просто на телефоне.

Comment: хорошо, если поднять сервер ну скажем на React, логика должна быть следующая, получается слушатель ставлю на firestore и при совпадении времени отправляю запрос или каК?

Comment: React, насколько я знаю, это для фронта. Если на JS писать, то тогда уж nodeJs нужен. А лучше на Spring поднять - хотя бы один язык будет (Java/Kotlin). Можно очень по разному. Многое зависит от кол-ва данных, например. По идее можно как-то так. Серверное приложение принимает от клиентов пуш-токены и записи со временем. Пишет их в БД. И пускает бесконечный цикл (лучше даже через Spring-овый `Cron`) в котором делает выборку всех записей и сверяет их с временем сервера. Коли время близкое - шлёт пуш по записанному в БД токену. Если свой сервер и своя БД то Firestore будет не нужен

Comment: Приветствую, не знаю как я react написал, я имел ввиду тоже nodejs, ну я сделал проще, при авторизации подписываю на топик,который равняется id компании, и при выходе из аккаунта отписываю, а на сервере просто каждую минуту получаю список записей

Comment: сверяю с текущем временем и отправляю уведомление на топик с id компании